# How to pass extra data using getOne in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a problem with react-admin's dataProvider. I made a custom provider:

```
const dataProvider = {
    getList: async (resource, options) => {
      const mapping = (item) => {
        return {
          id          : item.data.sid,
          published_at: new Date(item.data.created),
        }
      }
      const load = async (data) => {
        const getData = async (transcript) => {
          return {
            data: transcript,
          };
        };
        const transcripts = async () => {
          const params = {
            limit: 50,
            offset: 0,
            searchText: options.filter.q,
          }
          return (await axios.get(
            `https://${apiUrl}/v1/transcripts`,
            { params, headers }
          )).data;
        };
        const promises = (await transcripts()).map((transcript) =>
          getData(transcript)
        );
        return Promise.all(promises);
      };
      const list = await load()
      .then(res => res)
      const sortedList = list.map(mapping);
      return {
        data    : sortedList,
        total   : 10,
      }
    },
    getOne: async (resource, options) => {
      const rawSummary = (await axios.get(`https://${apiUrl}/v1/transcripts/${options.id}.summary`)).data;
      const rawTranscript = (await axios.get(`https://${apiUrl}/v1/transcripts/${options.id}.nlp`)).data;
      const data = {
        transcript: rawTranscript,
        summary   : rawSummary,
      }
      return {
        data: data,
      };
    }
}
```

getList works correct. I get data like:

```
[
    {
        data: {
            created: "2020-08-14T12:00:03.551Z",
            sid: "0dda80a33135bb73bd39d28be5176fe1d71fcf05",
            transcript: {
                created: "2020-08-14T12:00:03.551Z",
                updated: "2020-08-14T12:00:03.551Z",
                size: "2400848",
            },
        },
    },
    {
        data: {
            created: "2020-08-13T13:45:03.225Z",
            sid: "b62fd4837a965c23bb3403f32a50e6e9a1c193c7",
            transcript: {
                created: "2020-08-13T13:45:03.225Z",
                updated: "2020-08-13T13:45:03.225Z",
                size: "12690"
            },
        },
    },
    ...
]
```

But if I go thru a certain record, I expect to get an extra "transcript" and "summary", but log returns only record contains:

```
{
    id: "54710bd652f6901496091e440db976451f400529",
    published_at: Sun Aug 16 2020 12:10:02 GMT+0300,
}
```

Could you please give a hint how to add extra data? I added summary and transcript requests as properties to object of getList, but document's sizes are more than 2 Mb, so it took a lot of time to load.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Hi, Had u checked the "resource" object on get one. This object will have all data of the records.

Comment: @VishnuPrasad yep, for sure. It contains data from single collection's record - id and published_at. The question is how to pass extra data from other requests in getOne method :/

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the problem was on the surface. I just forgot to add "id" to data to be returned:

```
getOne: async (resource, options) => {
  const rawSummary = (await axios.get(`https://${apiUrl}/v1/transcripts/${options.id}.summary`)).data;
  const rawTranscript = (await axios.get(`https://${apiUrl}/v1/transcripts/${options.id}.nlp`)).data;
  const data = {
    transcript: rawTranscript,
    summary   : rawSummary,
  }
  return {
    data: {
      id : options.id,
      ...data,
    },
  };
}
```